# How to Access a Nested JSON Object with PHP

Tags: php, json, object

I have this nested object generated from accessing the Login of the API.
The "Token" will be different for each user login. To access other parts of the API, user have to login first. To do that, the "Token" value is required.

So now I am trying to extract the "Token" value from the nested object and place it in the header part of the POST request. Any idea how I can access the nested object?

Many thanks.

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Token": "2:BxeFG9E28lnG5gB5GiB1NgxXBPGjTl",
    "Name": "Administrator",
    "ClinicID": 0,
    "Admin": true,
    "UserAccessRight": {
      "id": 1,
      "dateCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "lastUpdated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "userid": 2,
      "waitingQueue": 2,
      "patient": 2,
      "appointment": 2,
      "consultation": 2,
      "dispensary": 2,
      "inventory": 2,
      "report": 2,
      "setting": 2
    }
  },
  "Success": true
}
```

I have tried this but fail

```
<?php require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client([
 'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ]
 ]);

$response = $client->post('http://localhost:81/Login',
 ['body' => json_encode(
    [
        "username" => "admin",
        "Password" => "123456"
    ]
    )]
   );

  echo '<pre>' . var_export($response->getStatusCode(), true).'</pre>';
  echo '<pre>' . var_export($response->getBody()->getContents(), 
   true) . '</pre>';


      $object = '<pre>' . var_export($response->getBody()->getContents()
     , true) . '</pre>';
      echo $object;

     $yummy = json_decode("$object");

      echo $yummy['Data'][1]->Token;
```

Comment: I have tried that but idk why cant access the object value,plz have a look at my updated answer

Comment: The error is "Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: Answer/Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a1688802677bf89725278a73549a4943a29fe90  Please delete your duplicate question.